# How to pass data from JSON or HTML to Galleria 'image' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I have a data, something like below

```
[
   {
      "picture": "http://i.imgur.com/7Osllxil.jpg",
      "name": "Kitty",
      "age": 2
   }
   //and so on
]
```

From the data above, I want to show a gallery using Galleria. In the gallery, every time the user see an image, I want to process the data above.

The code is like below. The full code can be see in JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/pajn8q3z/4/

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/7Osllxil.jpg" data-name="Kitty" data-age="2">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/7Osllxil.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/YACmI1G.jpg" data-name="Tom" data-age="3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YACmI1G.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/af4ZDy8.jpg" data-name="Felix" data-age="4">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/af4ZDy8.jpg"/>
    </a>
```

```
Galleria.run('#gallery');
Galleria.on('image', function(e){
    var name = 'Kitty'; //Where to get this?
    var age = 2; //Where to get this?
    $('#caption').html('Hi, my name is ' + name + '. My age is ' + age);
});
```

Since Galleria will construct its own DOM, how to pass the `name` and `age` data above to the `image` event?

If I use

```
console.dir(e.imageTarget);
```

it will show

```
<img width="153" height="230" style="display: block; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; max-width: none; max-height: none; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); width: 153px; height: 230px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 164px; opacity: 1;" src="http://i.imgur.com/7Osllxil.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, `e.imageTarget` is referring to the  DOM object. If you want to add the data to the data-attr of the dom, you can just use jQuery's [$data](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
$(e.imageTarget).data("name", "Tom");
```

Or [do it in the vanilla JS way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
e.imageTarget.dataset.name = "Tom";
```

---

[Update] The problem is that Galleria create a new DOM for you without setting the dataset.

So in this case [you have 3 options](http://galleria.io/docs/references/data/):

1. use HTML

   This would word as long as you have the data in the image element, not the anchor element.

   ```
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/7Osllxil.jpg"  data-name="Kitty" data-age="2">
   ```
2. use `dataConfig`

   ```
   Galleria.run('.galleria', {
       dataConfig: function(img) {
           return {
               description: $(img).next('p').html()
           }
       }
   ```
3. use `dataSource`

   ```
     var data = [
       {
     "picture": "http://i.imgur.com/7Osllxil.jpg",
     "name": "Kitty",
     "age": 2
     },
      {
     "picture": "http://i.imgur.com/7Osllxil.jpg",
     "name": "Kitty",
     "age": 2
     }
     ];
     Galleria.run('.galleria', {
          dataSource: data
      });
   ```

Comment: How do I know that particular target will have the name "Tom"?

Comment: @PetraBarus you can access it with `$(DOM ).data( "name" )`

Comment: @PetraBarus Oh I think I get what you mean now. Gimme a minute.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that way myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just got the answer, all I need to do is just put the data in the `img` tag, like below.

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/7Osllxil.jpg">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/7Osllxil.jpg" data-name="Kitty" data-age="2"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/YACmI1G.jpg">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YACmI1G.jpg" data-name="Tom" data-age="3"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/af4ZDy8.jpg">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/af4ZDy8.jpg" data-name="Felix" data-age="4"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

And in the event, I can use `e.galleriaData.original`.

```
Galleria.on('image', function(e){
    var o = $(e.galleriaData.original);
    var name = o.data('name');
    var age = o.data('age');
    $('#caption').html('Hi, my name is ' + name + '. My age is ' + age);
});
```

Working answer can be seen in this http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/pajn8q3z/